# iPhone objective c: unrecognized selector sent to instance AsyncImageLoader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, selector

I'm using this AsyncImageLoader to load images asynchronously: [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView).

When I try to load an image resource whit the method loadImageWithURL, I keep getting the error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

The class (AsyncImageLoader) is trying to perform the selector like this:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:success withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
```

My code is like this:

```
-(void)thumbImageLoadSucces:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"imageloadedsucces");

}

-(void)thumbImageLoadError:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"imageloadederror");

}
```

And then somewhere else in the same Controller:

```
[self.asyncImageLoader loadImageWithURL:url target:self.thumb success:@selector(thumbImageLoadSucces:) failure:@selector(thumbImageLoadError:)];
```

Can anybody tell me why I keep getting this error? I've tried the other solutions given to this error here on SO, but nothing helped (it was mostly a typo in the code, but I checked my code for errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have your target wrong. It needs to be:

```
[self.asyncImageLoader loadImageWithURL:url target:self success:@selector(thumbImageLoadSucces:) failure:@selector(thumbImageLoadError:)];
```

The async loader is going to perform those selectors on the target. So it's the target that needs to respond to them. Then in the success & failure methods you'll set the image on the image view.

Comment: Awesome. So simple, I just didn't immediately get that the target was referring to the selector target, not the UIImage target. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is with your target location
Try changing this

```
[self.asyncImageLoader loadImageWithURL:url target:self.thumb success:@selector(thumbImageLoadSucces:) failure:@selector(thumbImageLoadError:)];
```

into

```
[self.asyncImageLoader loadImageWithURL:url target:self success:@selector(thumbImageLoadSucces:) failure:@selector(thumbImageLoadError:)];
```

i.e. `self.thumb` into `self`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:success withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
```

You forgot to add the selector. You need to write like:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(thumbImageLoadSucces:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
```